# How to create a dynamic array for Mandrill API

Tags: php, arrays, mandrill

I want to send an email to multiple email addresses using one Mandrill API call, here is what we do to send to only one email:

```
<?php
    $mandrill_message = array(
        // ...blah blah, doesn't matter
        // To send to only one email address:
        'to' => array(
            array(
                'email' => $the_email,
            )
        ),
        // ...blah blah, doesn't matter
    );
?>
```

This is OK but while we want to send the message to multiple email addresses, we must have this:

```
<?php
    $mandrill_message = array(
        // ...blah blah, doesn't matter
        // To send to more than one email:
        'to' => array(
            array(
                'email' => $email_1,
            ),
            array(
                'email' => $email_2,
            ),
            array(
                'email' => $email_3,
            ),
        ),
        // ...blah blah, doesn't matter
    );
?>
```

As you can see, we've repeated the array part, now assuming we have this array:

```
$subscribers_email = array(
    'email_1@xxx.com',
    'email_2@xxx.com',
    'email_3@xxx.com'
);
```

How could we possibly make the mandrill code to use `$subscribers_email`? Of course we can write the email addresses in the mandrill code like:

```
<?php
    $mandrill_message = array(
        // ...blah blah, doesn't matter
        // To send to only one amil address:
        'to' => array(
            array(
                'email' => 'email_1@xxx.com',
            ),
            array(
                'email' => 'email_2@xxx.com',
            ),
            array(
                'email' => 'email_3@xxx.com',
            ),
        ),
        // ...blah blah, doesn't matter
    );
?>
```

But that's not what I want, imagine we need to make this dynamic and as a function, like:

```
function sendEmailToArray($subscribers_email){
        $mandrill_message = array(
            // ...blah blah, doesn't matter
            // To send to only one amil address:
            'to' => array(
                $subscribers_email
            ),
            // ...blah blah, doesn't matter
        );
    }
```

So I want to make that array in a dynamic way, is that possible?

Comment: what is the issue in making `$subscribers_email` as required by mandrill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert your array as your requirement.

Use this code

```
function sendEmailToArray($subscribers_email){
    //$subscribers_email = array(
    //    'email_1@xxx.com',
    //    'email_2@xxx.com',
    //    'email_3@xxx.com'
    //);

    $final_subscribers_email = array();
    foreach ($subscribers_email as $key => $value) {
        array_push($final_subscribers_email, array("email" => $value));
    }

    $mandrill_message = array(
        // ...blah blah, doesn't matter
        // To send to only one email address:
        'to' => $final_subscribers_email,
        // ...blah blah, doesn't matter
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_walk` for this.

```
$subscribers_email = array(
    'email_1@xxx.com',
    'email_2@xxx.com',
    'email_3@xxx.com'
);

sendEmailToArray($subscribers_email);

function sendEmailToArray($subscribers_email){
   // Convert the array
   array_walk($subscribers_email, function(&$input){
      $input = array('email' => $input);
   });

   // Send the emails
   $mandrill_message = array(
      'to' => array($subscribers_email),
   );
}
```